# ¿Como evitar que " se codifique como &quot; en Razor?

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, razor

Bueno la cuestión aquí es que ando trabajando en un archivo razor y ando queriendo crear un json a partir de un array en `vb.net` de la siguiente manera:

```
For Each ItineraryPnr In ItinerariesNode.ChildNodes
    arrayPnrRetrieve(contPnr) = New With {Key .trasactionId = ItineraryPnr.SelectSingleNode("TransactionId").InnerText, .isSucces = False, .provider = ItineraryPnr.SelectSingleNode("Provider").InnerText, .pnr = ItineraryPnr.SelectSingleNode("PNR").InnerText, .errors = Nothing}
    contPnr = contPnr + 1
Next

Dim serializerPnrModel As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim jsonPnrRQ As String = serializerPnrModel.Serialize(arrayPnrRetrieve)
```

Lo anterior me genera algo como lo siguiente y lo asigno a la variable `jsonPnrRQ`:

```
[
  {
   "trasactionId":"c592360b-3d29-4689-9683-8b53b4880099",
   "isSucces":false,
   "provider":"4O",
   "pnr":"DBZD2N",
   "errors":null
  }
]
```

Entonces al quererlo asignar a una variable `javascript` de la siguiente manera:

```
 @<script>
     var metadata = {};            

     metadata.jsonEx = {};
     metadata.jsonEx.pnrRetrieve = @jsonPnrRQ;
     metadata.jsonEx.sequenceNumber = "3";

  </script>
```

Me deja ciclado la pagina y me manda un error de sintaxis, siendo que la variable `jsonPnrRQ`al debuguearlo esta en un formato correcto.

El error es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

La pregunta sería si a alguien le a sucedido y tiene alguna solución para esto?

> Al imprimir mi objeto `Js` me lo muestra de la siguiente manera

```
 metadata.jsonEx = {};
 metadata.jsonEx.pnrRetrieve = [{&quot;trasactionId&quot;:&quot;c592360b-3d29-4689-9683-8b53b4880099&quot;,&quot;isSucces&quot;:false,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;4O&quot;,&quot;pnr&quot;:&quot;DBZD2N&quot;,&quot;errors&quot;:null}];
 metadata.jsonEx.sequenceNumber = "3";
```

Y creo que eso puede ser el problema, entonces, la otra pregunta sería, ¿Alguien tiene idea de por que me lo asigna así y como lo puedo solucionar? siendo que la variable `jsonPnrRQ` tiene bien su valor (esto porque aldebugearlo sale con el formato correcto).

Comment: como estas enviando el json que generas en vb.net al cliente? usas jquery con $.ajax  El codigo que usa JavaScriptSerializer en que contexto lo defines? esta en un [WebMethod]

Comment: el json lo uso solo en una directiva, ya que es la que me sirve para almacenar los datos que tengo que mandar al servicio y pedir ciertos datos.  pero el json no muestra nada al cliente. estoy trabajando con angular en la parte del front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo sgte:

```
metadata.jsonEx.pnrRetrieve = @Html.Raw(jsonPnrRQ);
```

El problema es que el contenido del string `jsonPnrRQ` se está codificando como HTML y esta convirtiendo los 
`"` en `&quot;`. Esto es como funciona Razor por defecto para evitar algunos problemas de seguridad.

En este caso queremos incrustar el contenido en el código JavaScript en lugar de mostrarlo como texto HTML, con `@Html.Raw()` se manda el contenido tal cual sin codificarlo.

Además ten en cuenta que JSON no es lo mismo que JavaScript. Te recomiendo cambiar el `JavaScriptSerializer` por otra librería que serialize JSON como [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: ok, tomare en cuenta lo de la librería, gracias funciono.